# Muted video doesnt show volume controls on Android internet browser

Tags: html, video, web

I have a simple video on a home page and it works perfect across chrome, safari, etc. It is `muted` but user can unmute or increase volume themselves.

However issue arrises when trying to play video in Android internet browser. The volume controls are nowhere to be found. Is there a way to have those controls come up without affecting other browsers.

This is the code used:

```
<video width="100%"  controls autoplay loop onclick="this.play()">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I had to add CSS to remove Download button as not needed at all (dont think it affects the volume but to complete all code used here it is):

```
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
 display:none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
 overflow:hidden;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
 width: calc(100% + 30px); /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

The only controll i get on android is video location and full screen:
[image: ScreenshotfAndroidPlayer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i was not able to find a way to show volume control on video in android internet browser. I was able to play sound by adding on click functionality.

```
<video width="100%"  controls autoplay muted loop onclick="this.muted = !this.muted">
```

This solution will turn on the sound on clicking the video after pressing play and will mute it on second click.